# insert another row after 5th td in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In OpenCart when I am showing the discounts in more number quantity of product it is showing in a default way just in a single row. But I tried to change the look and made it like this

```
<div class="discount">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <?php foreach ($discounts as $discount) { ?>
        <td class="test">
          <?php echo sprintf($text_discount, $discount['quantity'], $discount['price']); ?>
        </td>
      <?php } ?>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here it is showing okay when 5 discounts in a row. But now I want to insert another row after 5th td. I want to show another 5 tds inside another tr. So can someone help me how to do this in jQuery?

Comment: Don't you mean that you want to add another tr after the first row?  If you add it after the 5th td it will break the html.

Comment: Yes I want another tr just after another row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add another tr after the last one then this will do it...

```
$("<tr />").insertAfter(".discount table tr:last")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;
```

It's got no cells in it, so you'd need to add them as well, which you could do like this...

```
$("<tr><td/><td/><td/><td/><td/></tr>").insertAfter(".discount table tr:last")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".discount table tr td:eq(4)").after("<tr><td>.....</td></tr>");
```

try some thing like this

if you want to insert `tr` `td` after 5th `tr` use this

```
$(".discount table tr:eq(4)").after("<tr><td>.....</td></tr>");
```

Comment: Actually I want to insert another tr>td just after 5th td>tr

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".discount table tr td:nth-child(5)").append("</tr><tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

easier to conclude by 5 in a row on the php

```
<div class="discount">
    <table>
         <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($discounts); ) { ?>
              <tr>
                   <?php for ($j = 0; $j < 5 && $i < count($discounts); $j++, $i++) { ?>
                        <td class="test">
                            information
                        </td>
                   <?php } ?>
              </tr>
         <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
```